# Haskell. INNER JOIN of two lists

Tags: haskell

I have been asking google and trying to find the necessary tools to do this, but can't seem to find a solution to my problem.
The whole task is to use a dictionary to translate a list and keep only the unique values. For example the following inputs:

```
dict = [("a", "aa"), ("b", "bb")]
list1 = ["a","b","c","a","a","g"]
```

are supposed to yield the following output:

```
result = ['aa', 'bb']
```

This is here where I am stuck at so far:

```
main = do
    let dict = [("a", "aa"), ("b", "bb")]
    let list1 = ["a","b","c","g"]
    let keys = map fst dict
    let values = map snd dict
    let result = replace keys values list1
    print(result)
```

which yields

```
["aa","bb","c","g"]
```

So to solve this I was thinking that there might be a way to use `filter` or `map` or `foldl` in some way to do an inner join as follows:

```
let result = innerJoin values result
```

Currently I have something that looks like this:

```
innerJoin :: (Eq a) =>[a] -> [a] -> [a]
innerJoin xs     []     = xs
innerJoin []     ys     = ys
innerJoin (x:xs) (y:ys) = if (elem x (y:ys))
                         then x: innerJoin xs ys
                         else innerJoin xs ys


main = do
    let dict = [("a", "aa"), ("b", "bb")]
    let list1 = ["a","b","c","g"]
    let keys = map fst dict
    let values = map snd dict
    let list2 = innerJoin keys list1
    let result = replace keys values list2
    print(result)
```

But it returns `["aa","bb","c","g"]` and not the expected  `["aa","bb"]`. In the end I plan to finish it off with `nub`, but I am struggling with figuring out the innerJoin part.

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the answer below here is the solution to the problem:

```
innerJoin xs     []     = []
innerJoin []     ys     = []
innerJoin (x:xs) (y:ys) = if (elem x (y:ys))
                         then x: innerJoin xs ys
                         else innerJoin xs ys
catMaybes ls = [x | Just x <- ls]
genList x [] = []
genList [] y = []
genList x (y:ys) = lookup y x: genList x ys
func dict list =  do
    let keys = map fst dict
    let list1 = innerJoin keys list
    catMaybes (genList dict list1)
test1 = func [("a", "aa"),("e", "bb")] ["a","b","c","g","a"]
test2 = func [(1,11),(2,11),(4,44)] [1,2,3,1,2]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function you want for this is [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:lookup). For instance:

```
lookup "a" [("a", "aa"), ("b", "bb")] = Just "aa"
lookup "b" [("a", "aa"), ("b", "bb")] = Just "bb"
lookup "x" [("a", "aa"), ("b", "bb")] = Nothing   -- "x" is not in the list
```

The other function which is useful here is [`Data.Maybe.catMaybes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes): if you have a list like `[Just 1, Just 2, Nothing, Just 3, Nothing]` and apply `catMaybes` to it, you get `[1, 2, 3]`. So you can just combine `lookup` and `catMaybes` to get `catMaybes $ map (flip lookup dict) list1` as your desired solution. An additional refinement is to note that `Data.Maybe` defines `mapMaybe f xs` as being equivalent to `catMaybe (map f xs)`, so you can simplify that down to `mapMaybe (flip lookup dict) list1`.

Comment: there has been some progress, maybe you would find the edited post interesting and easier to answer :) !

Comment: @mkalns Ah, I see it now. But I’m not quite sure how that’s relevant to my answer — you’ve edited in your attempt at this problem, something which is always recommended, but I’m giving a different method for solving your problem which doesn’t use the same approach as yours.

Comment: For sure. Thanks a heapl!

Comment: Also, you can see the solution using your suggestion. Thanks :)